# syntax using rsync to remote server with id_rsa

Tags: ssh, rsync

What is wrong with my syntax when I want to backup files from a remote server?

I can connect to the server but I can not use rsync for backup, this fails:

```
rsync -auvtz --delete -e ssh -p 42 username@host.tld:/var/www/data  /home/user/dir
```

it says

```
Unexpected remote arg: username@host.tld:/var/www/data
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.1]
```

A similar command works fine on a server that does not use id_rsa key.

Comment: I think you need to quote arguments to the `ssh` command i.e. `-e "ssh -p 42" username@host.tld:/var/www/data . . .` I don't see any mention of `id_rsa` anywhere in your command, however the rules would be the same i.e. `-e "ssh -p 42 -i path/to/id_rsa"`. Alternatively, you might want to create an appropriate `~/.ssh/config` entry for the remote host - in which case, `rsync` should "just work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven’t stated that you’re using a non-standard port for SSH but I suspect that’s the case from your use of the `-p` option. If this is the case, you should quote the remote shell command that is specified with the `-e` option, like so:

```
rsync -auvtz --delete -e 'ssh -p 42' username@host.tld:/var/www/data /home/user/dir
```